# Нужна ли запятая после "из-за чего"?

Tags: пунктуация

В колокол бьют шесть раз, из-за чего(,) я вопросительно смотрю на подругу.

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

В колокол бьют шесть раз, из-за чего я вопросительно смотрю на подругу.

Это СПП с придаточным присоединительным, союзное слово "из-за чего".

Answer (score 2):

> Запятая после “из-за чего”

Нет там запятой. И быть не может.
А откуда возникла мысль её там поставить? И почему именно там?

> Уверен, автор вопроса был бы признателен вам за пояснение или правило.

Пояснение, оно же - правило, может только одно. ***Нет правила, которое бы требовало или допускало там простановку запятой.***

Вообще правила пишутся на те случаи, когда знак нужен. Это система с единичными исключениями на те случаи когда основное правило не действуют. Просить объяснить, почему знак не нужен, если непонятно, как рассуждал автор, предполагая наличие знака, бессмысленно. Это называется отсутствием мотивировки для знака.

Екатерина предположила, что автор считает необходимым ставить знак после союзного слова, мне бы такого в голову не пришло. Я вообще сильно сомневаюсь в подобной мотивировке, ибо это что-то совершенно невозможное, ну ей виднее. Но даже если она права, как можно объяснить-то это человеку, не догадываясь, зачем ему там запятая?!

Comment: Уверен, автор вопроса был бы признателен вам за пояснение или правило.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы убедиться, что запятая не нужна, замените союзное слово - местоимение  ***из-за чего*** другим словом, не игрющим  роль союза и не меняющим смысл предложения: ***В колокол бьют шесть раз, из-за этого я вопросительно смотрю на подругу.*** Выражение ***из-за этого*** (=из-за чего) является обычным обстоятельством, которое не нужно обособлять, так для этого нет никаких оснований.

Comment: Что бы в чем-то убеждаться, надо это "что-то" сформулировать. Я не вижу, откуда вообще идея взялась ставить там запятую. Ваш вариант ничем не лучше исходного. Если автор предполагал запятую после "чего" он может и после "этого" поставить. И ни в чем не убедится.

Comment: *После союза* ставить запятую - это клиника, за неё надо не доказывать, а пороть и оставлять на второй год. А если доказывать, что не союз, то они и будут думать, что после союза запятая нужна.